# Is there a security benefit to using a userid/password for mysqli_connect() on a MariaDB/PHP server?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

I'm having a hard time coming up with a benefit for requiring a password for MariaDB/PHP web apps, since the password will always be stored as plaintext *somewhere*.

Regardless of whether it's hardcoded in the mysqli_connect() call, or fed to mysqli_connect() from an ENV file or an environment variable or some other location, there doesn't seem to be any security benefit to having a password, since if the webserver can read it, so can anybody that can plant code in the web tree.

It seems like it would be better to set the account to allow password-less login from localhost, then restrict the MariaDB account to the server's IP Address.

Has anybody come up with anything more secure?

Any thoughts?

Comment: What about other applications on your localhost that could now interact with your database without a password? Wouldn't that be more difficult if a password would be stored in ENV or a file with permissions properly configured?

Comment: I don't get this logic. At all. How "set the account to allow password-less login" is *any* better than having a password. Looks like just abstract musing. The "benefit", if you like it, is in using a standard universal mechanism, without devising fancy schemes.

Comment: password-less could mean unix socket auth plugin requiring the unix user to match the mysql/mariadb which replaces the authentication to that of the unix user rather than a known string on a known IP. So not abstract, very concrete and invented, not necessary better or worse in all scenarios, but different. Really need to consider risk/benefit of scenarios, but no solutions are exceptionally robust and fault tolerant.

Comment: @lne : It's a dedicated host with no human users and no non-related applications
.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: The only "better" part is not having to store or recall or maintain a password. "Not having a password" isn't a "fancy scheme", in fact it's the opposite. Data that doesn't exist, doesn't need to be maintained.

Comment: But you still have to maintain a login anyway, don't you? On the one hand i tend to agree with you, using login/password is rather a habit than a security requirement. On the other hand, I fail to see what's wrong with this approach either.

Answer (score 0):

If someone would gain access to the files on your webserver then you would have much more important problems to worry about other than the leaked MySQL password.

The database password should not be hardcoded in your application. You can't keep the hardcoded password secret when using Version Control Software. You can't have separate credentials for your development and production software if it is hardcoded. **Database credentials should be stored in the environment variables.**

Direct database access should always be protected with a password to avoid accidental access by unauthorized parties. Imagine, what would happen if someone set a port forwarding or installed phpMyAdmin on your production server that has unrestricted access. By using privilege system you can restrict who has access to your database.

When running multiple applications that have access to separate logical databases, you can restrict which application has access to which database. This way you can minimize the damage if one application is hacked or has a terrible malfunction. If multiple tenants are using the same server you can guarantee the privacy of their data by providing separate credentials to each tenant.

The fact that the password is stored in plaintext is not important. These credentials should only ever be stored and used on that one server. If someone gains access to that password, then it means they already have access to your server. Secure-hashing is not going to protect anything at this point in time. These passwords are usually long unique strings of characters and are not reused anywhere else.

Comment: Since they have access to the server, they would also have access to the DB login./password the web app uses. This doesn't seem any more secure than not having a password.